Is storing socket objects in Map can cause issues in a production environment with larger amount of clients?
I'm using ocpp-rpc  package to run an OCPP server, currently I'm using Map to store the connected clients object, I want to reference them later.
I'm storing them like below
const connectedChargers = new Map();

server.on('client', async (client) => {
    console.log(`${client.identity} connected!`);

    connectedChargers.set(client.identity, client); // storing client reference
});

I want to know is this a best practice to do? Is there any better way to achieve this?
My system going to have thousands of clients that connecting to the server, so I need optimal way to handle this.
Also I tried to save them in the Redis, but it fails due to circular references.
Basically I need to know that my aproach is good or bad and if it is bad a better way to achieve this.
I tried to save them in the Redis, but it fails due to circular references. I want

I think your aproach works just fine. But you must note that connectedChargers must be referenced somewhere that outlives the server event listeners if you want to use it after the server stoped and got erased by the garbage collector.

redis is great if you want to scale using multiple server instances so you have a distributed cache

@cmgchess I tried to save it in Redis but It fails to serialize the client object due to circular references

What you are doing is fine, just make sure to clean them up upon disconnection. Something like this:
const connectedChargers = new Map();

server.on('client', (client) => {
    connectedChargers.set(client, client.identity);
});

server.on('disconnect' (client) => {
    connectedChargers.delete(client.identity);
});

Keeping a reference of the client object in a map is not concerning, even if you keep a million of them. The client object is kept in the ram anyway, you are just saving a key and a reference to the object.
Your real concern should be bandwidth, the amount of ram os need to keep a socket open and most importantly, the CPU usage required to process the messages received by those thousands of clients, specially if they are going to send a lot of messages!

Sure I will do a server monitoring and look into those parameters, btw Have you ever used this approach in a live application? If so it's great to have some more insights

Yes, I have, it was a high-throughput server and as I mentioned, CPU usage was the real bottleneck. I believe you are not going to have thousands of users over a night, what I recommend is not to get too obsessed with optimization at this stage, instead try to design some nice stress tests and monitor your app's resource usage. Try to find slow functions and improve them over time, but first, create something that works!

Thanks, yeah It wont have thousands users over a night, I just wanted to know that I'm on right track :)
